# Error " A JSON text must at least contain two octets!."

Tags: python, json, kissmetrics

I recently had to complete an export and then reimport of all of my Kissmetrics data in order to remove some erroneous events due to incorrect aliasing. I built a python program to generate a new JSON file (by stripping out some lines from the original JSON file). None of the contents of the lines that stayed in the file were altered.

I set up a data integration to upload my new JSON file back into the Kissmetrics system and recieved the error "A JSON text must at least contain two octets!."

```
{"_n": "visited site", "url": "foo.com", "_t": 1399796233, "referrer": "https://www.google.co.in/", "_p": "ziecbw+mnecncwk9x1edoda9+qc="}
{"_n": "search engine hit", "_t": 1399796234, "search terms": "not provided", "_p": "ziecbw+mnecncwk9x1edoda9+qc=", "search engine": "Google"}
{"_t": 1399795555, "page_viewed_in_category": "bar", "_p": "jen/1vdw9ufyh8kpihtymvrjbj4="}
```

The file was several hundred thousand lines long. I figured the error must've been in the way that I generated the JSON, so I attempted to do a binary search through the data to find the offending line. I tried splitting the data in two and uploading half the file. The theory was eventually help me find the line producing an error. Weirdly enough, once I split the file enough times, a previously error-producing file would not have either of its halfs produce an error.

Example:

File 1 - 1000 JSON lines and produces error when uploaded to KM

I then split file 1 into 2 files containing 500 lines each, file 2A and 2B.

File 2A - 500 lines and produces no error
File 2B - 500 lines and produces an error

This appears consistent with the theory that there are bad lines of JSON in the data. But it gets weird when we split file 2B into two files, file 3A and file 3B.

File 3A - 250 lines and produces no error
File 3B - 250 lines and produces no error

So it appears (and has been confirmed by Kissmetrics support) that the error is not in the actual contents of the JSON itself, but in the way the parser is reading my file.

Kissmetrics suggested I use JSON.dumps for writing the file inside of the normal .write method, as their theory was that the JSON file I generated had some sort of artifacts in the way the file was generated. I switched to using JSON.dumps to output the JSON file - same error.

The file that I'm writing is definitely all valid JSON - I can scan it back into Python and run through it no issue.

Any ideas on how I can fix the file?

Comment: It sounds like your large JSON is getting truncated to 0 bytes at some point during the upload and processing.  ("Must contain at least two octets" means that the input is 0 or 1 byte, not that the input has some corruption or bad content.)

Comment: Interesting. I'll see if I can get in contact with them about that. Thank you!!